# OpenCV Python Frequency Domain Filtering Result Is Not As Expected

Tags: python, fft, opencv, frequency-analysis

hope you are all doing well.

Right now I am doing a homework which requires me to create High Pass Filters in the frequency domain. I created all of my filters. After I apply my filters (of course after converting the input image to the frequency domain and then applying Inverse Fourier to get to spatial domain), the output images are in purple tones, whereas the input image is gray level. Here is the output from my Ideal High Pass Filter:

[image]

Here is the input image:

[image]

Here is my High Pass filter function:

```
import numpy as np

# The function takes two dimension inputs for the filter image;
# the third filter is D0, which defines the circle area of the High Pass Filter.
def idealHighPass(M, N, D0):
    # Initializing the filter with ones; since the filter is a complex function,
    # it has two channels, representing the real and imaginary parts:
    filter = np.ones((M, N, 2), dtype=np.uint8)
    
    # Scanning through each pixel and calculating the distance of each pixel
    # to the image center. If the pixel is within D0, it is changed to 0:
    for i in range(M):
        for j in range(N):
           filter[i][j] = 0

    return filter
```

Here is my main code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from idealHighPass import idealHighPass
from highButterworth import highButterworth
from highGaussian import highGaussian

#img = cv2.imread("airfield-05small-auto.tif")
img = cv2.imread("input.png")
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

m, n = img.shape

ft = cv2.dft(np.float32(img), flags=cv2.DFT_COMPLEX_OUTPUT)
ft_shifted = dft_shift = np.fft.fftshift(ft)

# - IDEAL HIGH-PASS FILTER EXECUTION START -

filter = idealHighPass(m, n, 80)
filter = filter.astype((np.float32))

applied = ft_shifted * filter
fshift_mask_mag = 20 * np.log(cv2.magnitude(applied[:, :, 0], applied[:, :, 1]))
f_ishift = np.fft.ifftshift(applied)
img_back = cv2.idft(f_ishift)
img_back = cv2.magnitude(img_back[:, :, 0], img_back[:, :, 1])
cv2.imwrite("high_passed.png", img_back)
print(img_back.shape)

imgplot = plt.imshow(img_back)
plt.show()

# - IDEAL HIGH-PASS FILTER EXECUTION END -
```

Comment: The problem is that you are displaying/saving with Pyplot, which applies a default colormap to the image. Use cv2.imshow() to view your results, not plt.imshow().

Comment: PS. In your high pass filter, you are doing that the slow way by iterating through the image pixel by pixel. It should be faster to just draw a black circle of the desired radius on your white background.

Comment: @fmw42 Yes, I checked about colormaps on Pyplot's documentary and got the result right after changing the colormap. For your second comment, would it be enough if I just created a circle in spatial domain and then transferred it to Fourier Domain. Would that yield the same HPF? By the way, thank you so much for your help!

Comment: All you need is to simply draw your black circle on a white background. That is the frequency domain high pass filter. I am not sure I understand your questions about creating a circle in the spatial domain. The transform of that to the frequency domain is not the same as drawing a circle in the frequency domain as you are effectively doing. The FFT of a circle is the Jinc function. They are not the same. The Jinc is similar to circular symmetric Sinc function. It oscillates while tapering. See formula 402 at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform

Comment: Completely understood. Thank you so much!

Comment: See my answer to a similar question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66935821/how-to-apply-a-lpf-and-hpf-to-a-fft-fourier-transform